# Remove div in shiny app's title

Tags: html, r, header, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm using `shinydashboard`, and I want to put an image in the title with the following code:

```
header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = div(img(src = 'logo.png',
                  height = 60,
                  width = 120))
)
```

Everything goes well, but when I open the app by chrome, in my browser's tag, it looks very weird like below.

[image]

Is there any way to keep this from showing on the browser and show some normal text?

```
<div> <img src="logo.png" height="60" width="120"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're overwriting Dashboard's Title, You've to explicitly mention the page title with `tags$title`

```
tags$title('This is my page')
```

For `shinydashboard`:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'This is my title', header, sidebar, body, skin='red')
```

Comment: but where should I put the `tags$title`, I'm using shinydashboard, it shows "Expected tag to be of type li", when I put it in the `dashboardHeader`; it doesn't work when I put it in `dashboardBody`.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution could be the following:

```
header <- dashboardHeader(
    title = HTML('<div> <img src="logo.png" height="60" width="120"/>')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but there is now in 2022 an argument `windowTitle` to `titlePanel`

`titlePanel(title, windowTitle = title)`

So it is simply a case of supplying that, as in the following where the tab gets its own text string:

```
`titlePanel(
title=htmltools::div(
    htmltools::img(
    src="Transparent Logo No Slogan.png",style="width:50px; height:50px"),
    "my application title"
 ),
 windowTitle = "my tab title"
 )`
```